# vue.js how to bind a property to a method return value when using TypeScript and vue-property-decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a single file vue component written in TypeScript. I use some component methods in the template to bind properties, but the dom stays empty for those values.

The template (part of it, cut for simplicity) is like so:

```
<div class="order-items">
    <div class="order-item" v-for="(item, itemIndex) in order.items">
        <img class="order-item-icon" :src="getIcon(item.name)" />
        <span class="order-item-name">{{ itemsList[item.name].name }}</span>
        <span class="order-item-amount">{{ getPlayerAmount(item.name) }}/{{ item.amount }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the script part, there are those methods. I am using [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator), not sure how much of an impact that can have:

```
@Emit() getPlayerAmount(itemName: string): string {
    if (this.inventory[itemName]) {
        return `'${this.inventory[itemName].amount}'`;
    } else {
        return '0';
    }
}

@Emit() getIcon(itemName: string): string {
    const icon = Items.getItemData(itemName).icon;
    return icon;
}
```

Those methods are called by my template, as seen above. I have tried to put breakpoints in the code and the methods do get called and return the correct value. Yet, the dom stays empty. The `order-item-icon` img tag doesn't have an src, and the `order-item-amount` span is missing the first part before the `/`.

Is there something particular I'm supposed to do for binding properties to component methods?

Comment: It shouldnt be a problem to have a method within a property. Maybe there is something wrong with your function or data? Did you try printing the result somewhere else? Like, what happens if you just put a `<div>{{ getIcon(item.name) }}</div>` in the loop?

Comment: Showing raw variables works. In my template there's a `{{ item.amount}}` and this one appears. But the part before the slash that calls a method doesn't. Also my breakpoints on the method get triggered with the correct parameter. Everything seems to run fine, except what the method returns is just not appearing in the dom at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decorated with `Emit`, the return Vue of the method is [used to determine if the event should be emitted or not](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/master/src/vue-property-decorator.ts#L115).

In other words, methods decorated with `Emit` [will always return `undefined`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/master/src/vue-property-decorator.ts#L117).

**Solution:** remove the decorator and emit the events manually.

The equivalent code is:

```
getPlayerAmount(itemName: string): string {
    this.$emit('get-player-amount', itemName);
    if (this.inventory[itemName]) {
        return `'${this.inventory[itemName].amount}'`;
    } else {
        return '0';
    }
}

getIcon(itemName: string): string {
    const icon = Items.getItemData(itemName).icon;
    if (icon) this.$emit('get-icon', itemName);
    return icon;
}
```